# Unexpected result when subtracting value from list element

Tags: c++, list, stl

I have list of structures like this

```
struct
{
    size_t r,q;
}
```

and maks_q is size_t variable. With code

```
cout << (*lista.begin()).q - maks_q << "=" << (*lista.begin()).q << "-" << maks_q;
```

i got this result:

```
4294967270=2839-2865
```

Am i doing something stupid? Both sides should equal.

Comment: This is normal behaviour.

Comment: It is equal mod 2^32. (Unsigned arithmetic rules apply)

Comment: Well, I should have get some rest before asking question. Thanks I've just forgot that I am using unsigned variables.